# ¿Como limitar el numero de caracteres en un JTextField en Java?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Quisiera limitar el numero de caracteres que se ingresan en un JTextField en java

Comment: Mira esta clase: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/LimitJTextFieldinputtoamaximumlength.htm

Comment: ¿qué investigaste? el enlace de @A.Cedano me hace pensar que muy probablemente es algo rápido de encontrar si buscas con cierto cariño

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que usar KeyListener

```
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 

    {
if (jTextFieldName.getText().length()== limite) 

         e.consume(); 
    }
```

limite es el número de caracteres que deseas cómo máximo.

```
e.consume()
```

elimina los caracteres que sean introducidos cuando se alcanza el límite.